# Почему меняются цвета после перезагрузки сцены?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-editor

На сцене есть куб со стандартным материалом и камера. Сцена имеет индекс 0.
Есть код, который при нажатии клавиши `Space` перезагружает сцену:

```
...
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

class ...{

    void Update(){

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){

            SceneManager.LoadScene (0);

        }
    }
}
```

До перезагрузки сцена выглядит так:
[image: Сцена до перезагрузки]
После так:
[image: Сцена после перезагрузки]
Что могло вызвать такое изменение цветов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема только в редакторе (т.к. там свет в фоне вычисляется всё ещё). В билде такого не будет.

Для починки в редакторе зайдите в *Window* -> *Lighting* -> *Settings* -> Вкладка *Scene* -> отключите *Continuous Baking* -> Нажмите на *Generate Lightning*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]